# Probability Question: Round table meeting

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Six delegations have a round table meeting. The meeting organization randomly arranges the seat for them. It is important to consider who is sitting to the left or right for each delegation. How many ways to arrange the seat?

(A) $720$

(B) $120$

(C) $60$

(D) $30$

I used a cyclic permutation to answer this question, $(6-1)!=120$. Is this correct?

Comment: As the question is posed, you are correct. Of note is that if the question cared only about who sat next to who, and not specifically left or right, it would be $60$.

Comment: @RandomUser can you explain why the answer is 60?

Comment: Because person A sitting to your left and person B sitting to your right is the same as person B sitting to your left and person A to your right. However that's not the way the question is worded. It specifically asks about left and right, so the answer is 120 for this question. I thought I would include it as an expansion to the idea.

Comment: If you only cared about who was next to who, you would consider ABCDEF clockwise the same as AFEDCB clockwise, giving another division by 2

Comment: @RossMillikan So what is the correct answer? I stick to 120 but I'm sure about that.

Comment: @RandomUser So the answer is 120?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sorry if I confused you with talking about reflections. It just seems likely that if you're working on cyclic permutations, they'll come up soon. Just giving you a bit of a heads up.

Comment: Yes, 120 is correct for your problem.  @RandomUser was showing that if reflections were considered equivalent (like rotations are considered equivalent) you would divide by 2 again to get 60.

Comment: Alright then, thank you @RossMillikan. :)

Comment: For this problem, you are expected to use $5!$, and anything else would be marked as wrong. In the real world, things are not so clear, some chairs are closer to the bar.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas for confirming my answer & the other. :)

Comment: I need to know what the game is. I understand the first two, then don't. What is foll? Infinite geometric series come up naturally in this kind of setup, because A's win comes in first throw or third or fifth or $\dots$.

Comment: I do not know what and so on means. One reasonable interpretation is that then B wins with $3$, $4$, $5$, or $6$, and if not then $A$ wins with $3$ to $6$ and so on. But then it is a finite game. I can make up a game for which the given answer is correct, but it will not sound like what you have partly described.

Comment: Could you please tell me what kind of game you make for which the given answer is correct? Could you describe it like what the problem should be so the correct answer as the same as the solution manual?

Comment: For example, A and B alternate. A wins if she gets a $6$. B tosses  a die and wins if she gets a $5$ or a $6$, and so on forever. So A wins if first is a $6$ (prob. $1/6$). She also wins if she misses (prob. $5/6$) and B also misses (prob. $4/6$) and on her next throw A gets a $6$. This has prob. $(5/6)(4/6)(1/6)$. But A also wins if she misses, B misses, A misses, B misses, A gets a $6$. This has probability $(5/6\cdot 4/6)^2(1/6)$. And so on forever. We get a geometric series, add up. (There is a neater way of solving the problem.)

Comment: Well, you asked for the sum from $0$, and that's what I produced. I could produce a story for sum from $1$, as you can. You just have to be careful about the first three or four cycles. If you have real trouble I can check it, but need to cook now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $6$ spots:

_, _, _, _, _, _.

In the first spot, there are $6$ choices, any of the $6$ can fit, then in the next spot, there are only $5$ choices since one of the $6$ is at spot $1$.

In the end, you will have $6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 720$ choices.

---

Ignore what I have above, those are for non-round table problem.

Your answer is correct.

Comment: But the fact that the table is round is probably meant to mean that rotations are considered the same.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html

Comment: all right.. my bad, didn't give too much thought to the round table.

Comment: As @RossMillikan said, this is round table. My lecturer told me to use cyclic permutation.